# Exact lyrics and meaning of the eulogy to Bhishma in Mahabharata

Tags: mahabharata, identification-request, shloka, bhishma

I am seeing differing versions of a eulogy to Bhishma cited from the Mahabharata literature.

One version is:

> Kshatriya satyawadi cha
>
> Tapasvi neeyata vrata
>
> Ripushmati dayavanastha
>
> Tsamat bhism prishaspithah

The other version is the following,

> Kshatriya satyavaadi cha
>
> Tapasvi neeyata vrata
>
> Ripushmati dayavanascha
>
> Tasmat bheeshmo Vrishah Smritah

There is not much difference between the first three lines of the two differing versions, but the last lines seems to convey (from my limited knowledge of Sanskrit) markedly different meanings.

I'm not sure which portion of Mahabharata the passage is from, but if it is from the earlier chapters where Bhishma is introduced as a young Kuru prince, then the use of 'pithah' doesn't make sense.

I'd appreciate it if someone can quote the exact verse from an authentic source of Mahabharata and also explain the entire meaning of the passage.

Comment: AFAIK There is similar verse related to Karna not Bhishma in Mahabharata. `बरह्मण्यः सत्यवादी च तपस्वी नियतव्रतः
     रिपुष्व अपि दयावांश च तस्मात कर्णॊ वृषा समृपः`

Comment: Do you know the Chapter and Parva where this verse is mentioned.

Comment: I'd like to know that as well. May be @KeshavSrinivasan can answer. Wish tagging works in SE.

Comment: @Yogi Please check this: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs07155.htm

Answer (score 1):

I think this shloka is from [Drona Parva 155.](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs07155.htm)

> 24 बरह्मण्यः सत्यवादी च तपस्वी नियतव्रतः
>
> रिपुष्व अपि दयावांश च तस्मात कर्णॊ वृषा समृपः
>
> 24 brahmaṇyaḥ satyavādī ca tapasvī niyatavrataḥ
>
> ripuṣv api dayāvāṃś ca tasmāt karṇo vṛṣā smṛpaḥ

[image]

However, It is said for Karna.